# Why error when running "pod install": Class AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

Error when running "pod install"
==> Class AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1f40dfb78) and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x10d21c2c8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[35545]: Class AMSupportURLSession is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1f40dfbc8) and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x10d21c318). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
[image: Podfile]
[image: error]

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution: need to open terminal by Rosetta because I'm using M1 chip